# How let-such-that expressions could be done in Dafny 3.1.0?

Tags: dafny

Expressions let-such-that that worked in previous releases of Dafny do not work in Dafny 3.1.0. For example, the following code (also in https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/ABZpf) raise the error: "to be compilable, the value of a let-such-that expression must be uniquely determined".

```
datatype NNF_Formula =   F 
                       | T
                       | V(prop:string) 
                       | NegV(prop:string) 
                       | EX(f:NNF_Formula) 
                       | AX(f:NNF_Formula) 
                       | EG(f:NNF_Formula) 
                       | AG(f:NNF_Formula) 
                       | ER(f1:NNF_Formula,f2:NNF_Formula) 
                       | AR(f1:NNF_Formula,f2:NNF_Formula) 
                       | EF(f:NNF_Formula)  
                       | AF(f:NNF_Formula) 
                       | EU(f1:NNF_Formula,f2:NNF_Formula) 
                       | AU(f1:NNF_Formula,f2:NNF_Formula) 
                       | EUsel(f1:NNF_Formula,f2:NNF_Formula) 
                       | AUsel(f1:NNF_Formula,f2:NNF_Formula) 
                       | Or(f1:NNF_Formula,f2:NNF_Formula)
                       | And(f1:NNF_Formula,f2:NNF_Formula) 

function method family(alpha: NNF_Formula): nat {
  match alpha
  case F => 0
  case T => 1
  case V(_) => 2
  case NegV(_) => 3
  case AX(_) => 4
  case EX(_) => 5
  case AG(_) => 6
  case EG(_) => 7
  case AR(_, _) => 8
  case ER(_, _) => 9
  case AF(_) => 10
  case EF(_) => 11
  case AU(_, _) => 12
  case EU(_, _) => 13
  case AUsel(_, _) => 14
  case EUsel(_, _) => 15
  case Or(_, _) => 16
  case And(_, _) => 17
}

// ORDER IN NNF FORMULAS

predicate method leq_string(s1:string,s2:string) { 
s1 == "" || (s2 != "" && s1[0] <= s2[0] && ( s1[0] == s2[0] ==> leq_string(s1[1..],s2[1..])))
}

lemma antisym_leq_string_Lemma (s1:string, s2:string)
requires leq_string(s1,s2)  && leq_string(s2,s1) 
ensures s1 == s2
{
if s1 != "" && s2 != "" { antisym_leq_string_Lemma(s1[1..],s2[1..]); }
}


predicate method leq_NNF_Formula (alpha:NNF_Formula, beta:NNF_Formula)
{
if family(alpha) < family(beta) then true
else if family(alpha) > family(beta) then false
else if family(alpha) <= 1 then true
else if 2 <= family(alpha) <= 3 then leq_string(alpha.prop,beta.prop) 
else if 4 <= family(alpha) <= 7 || 10 <= family(alpha) <= 11 then leq_NNF_Formula(alpha.f,beta.f) 
else leq_NNF_Formula(alpha.f1,beta.f1) && (alpha.f1 == beta.f1 ==> leq_NNF_Formula(alpha.f2,beta.f2)) 
}

lemma minimum_formula_Lemma (s:set<NNF_Formula>)
requires s != {}
ensures exists phi :: phi in s && forall psi :: psi in s-{phi}  ==> (leq_NNF_Formula(phi,psi) && psi != phi)

function method pick_minimum_formula(s: set<NNF_Formula>): NNF_Formula
requires s != {}
{
minimum_formula_Lemma(s); 
var phi :| phi in s && forall psi :: psi in s-{phi}  ==> (leq_NNF_Formula(phi,psi) && psi != phi);
phi
}
```

For clarity, I have omitted the proof of the lemma, but it can be proved. I have also complicated a bit the ensures of the lemma for ensured uniqueness. In previous releases of Dafny also this works:
ensures exists phi :: phi in s && forall psi :: psi in s  ==> leq_NNF_Formula(phi,psi).

I need some way of iteration on sets of NNF_Formula, is there a different way to do this on Dafny 3.1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error could certainly serve to be clearer.

This scenario is only disallowed for *function methods*. However, you could write it in an ordinary `method` and it would be fine.

```
method pick_minimum_formula(s: set<NNF_Formula>) returns (nnf: NNF_Formula)
requires s != {}
{
minimum_formula_Lemma(s); 
var phi :| phi in s && forall psi :: psi in s-{phi}  ==> (leq_NNF_Formula(phi,psi) && psi != phi);
nnf := phi;
}
```

You could also write it as a `function`, and it would be fine.

However, a `function method` does require that any let-such-that expression be unique. The reason is that a compiled let-such-that expression might be non-deterministic; on the other hand, any function must to be deterministic. But a `function method` must be a method whose output matches the result of the function! This cannot be guaranteed if the method would be nondeterministic.